# Связать таблицы. Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Как построить связь при такой задаче и вообще можно ли такое сделать

Table1 содержит список товар которыми владею я

```
user_id | product_id | status
```

Table2 содержит информацию о этих товарах

```
product_id | title | description | size
```

Одним запросом можно достать всё из Table2(список всех  товаров) и добавить ко всех колонку status? если данный товар привязан к user_id, то статус берём из Table1 иначе 0

Table1

```
user_id | product_id | status
1                 1                       5
1                 2                       3
```

Table2

```
product_id | title | description | size
1                       Title1   Description1  2
2                       Title2   Description2  31
3                       Title3   Description3  3
4                       Title4   Description4  12
```

Мне должно вернуть

```
product_id | title | description | size | status
1                       Title1   Description1  2        5
2                       Title2   Description2  31      3
3                       Title3   Description3  3        0
4                       Title4   Description4  12      0
```

В Java мне надо чтобы в классе например User было поле

```
private Set<Product> products;
```

- тут лежал результат выборки, какие есть вариант решения?

Comment: Как вариант сделать в базе вью с такими данными (product_id | title | description | size | status ) , которые легко выводятся на уровне скл и потом энтити строить по вью, а не по таблицам.

Comment: Hibernate позволяет автоматически закинуть вьюхи в базу? Можете дать ссылку где почитать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет, hibernate не делает вьюхи. Я предлагаю в базе сделать вью самому.

Answer (score 0):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;  
    //...     

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<ItemEntry> items;

    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product{

    //...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

[Более подробный пример](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)